# Throttling Mule Messages in Mule

Tags: mysql, mule, esb, throttling

I've a polling process in Mule that queries a MySQL database every 30 seconds and sends an email to a recipient. How do I limit to sending just 1 email regardless of the polling cycle whether it be 30 seconds or 15 seconds? I'm open to a counter in the mysql db as well if that's an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Write a condition which will only send an email if emailSentFlag == false.

Use choice router to create the condition, and objectstore to hold the emailSentFlag value.

```
<flow...>
        ....
        <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore__Configuration" key="emailSentFlag" defaultValue-ref="#[false]" targetProperty="flowVars.emailSentFlag" doc:name="retrieve emailSentFlag"/>
        <choice doc:name="IsEmailSent?">
            <when expression="#[flowVars.emailSentFlag == true]">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Email Already Sent"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="" user="" password="" to="" from="" subject="test" cc="" bcc="" replyTo="" responseTimeout="10000" ref="Gmail" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="Gmail"/>
                <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore__Configuration" key="emailSentFlag" value-ref="#[true]" doc:name="store emailSentFlag"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
```

Also explore the TTL and Persistence feature of objectstore, it could be useful to you.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could use queueing(JMS) for your use case, before sending the "data" to jms would add a delay. You could do this like this

```
  <message-properties-transformer overwrite="true" doc:name="Add DELAY in sending the Response to Queue">
     <add-message-property key="Content_Type" value="application/json"/>
     <add-message-property key="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" value="${aupost.retry.timeout}"/>
 </message-properties-transformer>
```

Then add jms consumer to consume the message and send the email accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sample flow to show? You may be able to use collection/message aggregators but looking at flow first would help to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a vm queue in the end of your flow where the poller picks the data from the sql database.

In other flow, invoke the vm queue using a mule requester as an inbound connector inside a poll then set whatever frequency you want for the mail in the poll frequency using a cron expression or fixed-scheduler. Something like the below code:-

```
 <flow name="db_poll">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <db:no-operation-selected config-ref="" doc:name="Database"/>
    </poll>
    <logger message="invoking the database in the poll.. every 30 secs" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="email_queue" connector-ref="VMformail" doc:name="VM"/>
</flow>
<flow name="email_poll">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="1" timeUnit="DAYS"/>
        <mulerequester:request-collection resource="VMformail" timeout="100000" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
    </poll>
    <logger message="send an email" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
</flow>
```